# AVL Tree - Counting N_Nodes to print element by postion c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, avl-tree

Hello StackOverFlow members, I'm new here and I need your help. I'm solving a problem, and I have to do this the most efficient way. The main point of this program is to read values, remove values and print values by a certain position (Thats my problem). I have to create (maintain) a O(N * log(N)) solution in this.
The input is like. Read N lines.

Input:

```
8 (N-> N Numbers)
INS 100 (Add 100 to the tree)
INS 200 (Add 200 to the tree)
INS 300 (Add 300 to the tree)
REM 200 (Remove the number 200 from the tree)
PER 1 (Have to output the biggest number in the tree-> Shoud print 300)
INS 1000 (Add 1000 to the tree)
PER 1 ((Have to output the biggest number in the tree-> Shoud print 1000))
PER 2 (I have to output the second biggest number so:  300)
```

There is my full code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

// An AVL tree node
struct node
{
    int key;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
    int height;
};
// A utility function to get maximum of two integers
int max(int a, int b);
// A utility function to get height of the tree
int height(struct node *N)
{
    if (N == NULL)
            return 0;
    return N->height;
}
// A utility function to get maximum of two integers
int max(int a, int b)
{
    return (a > b)? a : b;
}
/* Helper function that allocates a new node with the given key and
    NULL left and right pointers. */
struct node* newNode(int key)
{
    struct node* node = (struct node*)
                                            malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    node->key   = key;
    node->left   = NULL;
    node->right  = NULL;
    node->height = 1;  // new node is initially added at leaf
    return(node);
}
// A utility function to right rotate subtree rooted with y
// See the diagram given above.
struct node *rightRotate(struct node *y)
{
    struct node *x = y->left;
    struct node *T2 = x->right;
    // Perform rotation
    x->right = y;
    y->left = T2;
    // Update heights
    y->height = max(height(y->left), height(y->right))+1;
    x->height = max(height(x->left), height(x->right))+1;
    // Return new root
    return x;
}
// A utility function to left rotate subtree rooted with x
// See the diagram given above.
struct node *leftRotate(struct node *x)
{
    struct node *y = x->right;
    struct node *T2 = y->left;
    // Perform rotation
    y->left = x;
    x->right = T2;
    //  Update heights
    x->height = max(height(x->left), height(x->right))+1;
    y->height = max(height(y->left), height(y->right))+1;
    // Return new root
    return y;
}
// Get Balance factor of node N
int getBalance(struct node *N)
{
    if (N == NULL)
            return 0;
    return height(N->left) - height(N->right);
}
struct node* insert(struct node* node, int key)
{
    /* 1.  Perform the normal BST rotation */
    if (node == NULL)
            return(newNode(key));
    if (key < node->key)
            node->left  = insert(node->left, key);
    else
            node->right = insert(node->right, key);
    /* 2. Update height of this ancestor node */
    node->height = max(height(node->left), height(node->right)) + 1;
    /* 3. Get the balance factor of this ancestor node to check whether
           this node became unbalanced */
    int balance = getBalance(node);
    // If this node becomes unbalanced, then there are 4 cases
    // Left Left Case
    if (balance > 1 && key < node->left->key)
            return rightRotate(node);
    // Right Right Case
    if (balance < -1 && key > node->right->key)
            return leftRotate(node);
    // Left Right Case
    if (balance > 1 && key > node->left->key)
    {
            node->left =  leftRotate(node->left);
            return rightRotate(node);
    }
    // Right Left Case
    if (balance < -1 && key < node->right->key)
    {
            node->right = rightRotate(node->right);
            return leftRotate(node);
    }
    /* return the (unchanged) node pointer */
    return node;
}
/* Given a non-empty binary search tree, return the node with minimum
   key value found in that tree. Note that the entire tree does not
   need to be searched. */
struct node * minValueNode(struct node* node)
{
    struct node* current = node;
    /* loop down to find the leftmost leaf */
    while (current->left != NULL)
            current = current->left;
    return current;
}
struct node* apagaNode(struct node* root, int key)
{
    // STEP 1: PERFORM STANDARD BST DELETE
    if (root == NULL)
            return root;
    // If the key to be deleted is smaller than the root's key,
    // then it lies in left subtree
    if ( key < root->key )
            root->left = apagaNode(root->left, key);
    // If the key to be deleted is greater than the root's key,
    // then it lies in right subtree
    else if( key > root->key )
            root->right = apagaNode(root->right, key);
    // if key is same as root's key, then This is the node
    // to be deleted
    else
    {
            // node with only one child or no child
            if( (root->left == NULL) || (root->right == NULL) )
            {
                    struct node *temp = root->left ? root->left : root->right;
                    // No child case
                    if(temp == NULL)
                    {
                            temp = root;
                            root = NULL;
                    }
                    else // One child case
                         *root = *temp; // Copy the contents of the non-empty child
                    free(temp);
            }
            else
            {
                    // node with two children: Get the inorder successor (smallest
                    // in the right subtree)
                    struct node* temp = minValueNode(root->right);
                    // Copy the inorder successor's data to this node
                    root->key = temp->key;
                    // Delete the inorder successor
                    root->right = apagaNode(root->right, temp->key);
            }
    }
    // If the tree had only one node then return
    if (root == NULL)
          return root;
    // STEP 2: UPDATE HEIGHT OF THE CURRENT NODE
    root->height = max(height(root->left), height(root->right)) + 1;
    // STEP 3: GET THE BALANCE FACTOR OF THIS NODE (to check whether
    //  this node became unbalanced)
    int balance = getBalance(root);
    // If this node becomes unbalanced, then there are 4 cases
    // Left Left Case
    if (balance > 1 && getBalance(root->left) >= 0)
            return rightRotate(root);
    // Left Right Case
    if (balance > 1 && getBalance(root->left) < 0)
    {
            root->left =  leftRotate(root->left);
            return rightRotate(root);
    }
    // Right Right Case
    if (balance < -1 && getBalance(root->right) <= 0)
            return leftRotate(root);
    // Right Left Case
    if (balance < -1 && getBalance(root->right) > 0)
    {
            root->right = rightRotate(root->right);
            return leftRotate(root);
    }
    return root;
}

int imprime(struct node *root,int targetPos,int curPos)
{
    if(root != NULL)
    {
            int newPos = imprime(root->left, targetPos, curPos);
            newPos++;
            if (newPos == targetPos)
            {
                    printf("%d\n", root->key);
            }
            return imprime(root->right, targetPos, newPos);
    }
    else
    {
            return curPos;
    }
}

int main()
{
  struct node *root = NULL;
  int total=0;
  int n,b;
  string a;
  cin >> n;
  for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
          cin >> a >> b;
          if(a=="INS")
                  {root = insert(root, b);total=total+1;}
          else
          if(a=="REM")
                   {root = apagaNode(root, b);total=total-1;}
          else
                  imprime(root, total-b+1, 0);
  }
    return 0;
}
```

The only way i found to print a number by position using this tree is by search for it with a O(N) solution, which is very slow

Function I'm using:

```
int imprime(struct node *root,int targetPos,int curPos)
{
    if(root != NULL)
    {
            int newPos = imprime(root->left, targetPos, curPos);
            newPos++;
            if (newPos == targetPos)
            {
                    printf("%d\n", root->key);
            }
            return imprime(root->right, targetPos, newPos);
    }
    else
    {
            return curPos;
    }
}
```

I know that there is a O(N * log(N)) printing by counting the N_nodes, when inserting, removing, and during the rotations. But the problem is that i can not understand how to do it, because I'm a little bit lost with this algorithm. can somebody help me?

Should I count the n_nodes just on rotations? How can i count them?

Comment: Does `n_nodes` mean the number of nodes in a subtree?

Comment: Yes it is... @ILoveCoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If a new node is created, it has only one node in its subtree(it is obvious).
2. A number of elements in subtree of a node can change only if it either lies on the path from the root to a newly inserted/removed node or it is rotated. There are `O(log n)` such nodes per insertion/deletion, so we can update values for all of them without making the time complexity worse.
3. We can define the following functions:

   ```
   int getSubTreeSize(Node* node) {
       if (node != nullptr)
           return node->subTreeSize;
       else
           return 0;
   }

   void update(Node* node) {
       if (node != nullptr) {
           node->subTreeSize = getSubTreeSize(node->left) + 
                               getSubTreeSize(node->right) + 1;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Now all we have to do is to call this function for all nodes that we visited during the traversal when we insert/delete a node and for those that were rotated. One subtle moment: when we call `update` during the rotation, we should update the highest node after those that are located lower.

Comment: How should i call function update for example in the right totation? Just ti make sure I will do it well

Comment: @Pablo Something like: update(y->left); update(x->right); update(y); update(x) at the end of the function.

Comment: I added everything well on the code, but i'm doing something wrong. can you check the last answer i wrote on this topic. I explicit everything i did. Thank you btw

Answer (score 0):

The AVL Tree is not an optimal data structure for this problem. The solutions proposed are growing the node to add size as well as height information, whereas the original AVL Tree has only a two bit balance field.

A better data structure is the Weight Balanced Tree. It stores the sub-tree size only, not the height or the balance. The algorithms were developed by Hirai and Yamamoto (2011) 'Balancing Weight-Balanced Trees' Journal of Functional Programming / 21 (3): Pages 287-307, based on work by Nievergelt and Reingold in 1972.

See [Kazu Yamamoto's web page](http://www.mew.org/~kazu/proj/weight-balanced-tree/).

Comment: Could not be the optimal solution, but I know its ok for what i need. But thanks anyway, i will take a look.